# Ruby + Mongoid: how to make a required field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4

I use the githead version of Mongoid (because of Rails 4) and I want to make a field required document with:

```
class MyClass
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name,              type: String, required: true
```

And I have this error:

```
Problem: Invalid option :required provided for field :name. Summary: Mongoid requires that you only provide valid options on each field definition in order to prevent un...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `validates_presence_of`, so your class would look like this:

```
class MyClass
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

For further documentation on validation on mongoid, you can use http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html.